# How to execute some task at particular day of week?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I made one scheduler in c# mvc but I want to execute it on particular day of week.I also want to execute only one time at that day and it should not repeat again at same day.I am unaware about how to do it so  so please can anyone help me with scheduling task on particular day of week. I used. Net framework v4. 0

Comment: You can either use inbuilt windows task scheduler directly or if you want to schedule it programmatically, use TaskScheduler package

Answer (score -1):

Look at the DateTime class, in particular the DayOfWeek property. That should give you what you need.

Comment: #Steve Todd is it possible to do same thing from web. Config? do you know how?